# Don't list parent of two crossref'd entries within reference list unless cited (biblatex-chicago)

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, biblatex-chicago

The `biblatex-chicago` manual (p.88) states:

> The Manual (15.37) specifies that if you cite several contributions to the same collection, all (including the collection itself) may be listed separately in the list, which the package does automatically, using the default inclusion threshold of 2 in the case both of crossref’ed and xref’ed entries.

So the package automatically includes the parent reference if two or more child references are cited in the text. But since the *Manual* gives this as optional (they ***may*** be listed separately) I was wondering, is there a way to have `biblatex-chicago` only list the parent entry in the reference list as long as the parent itself is also explicitly `\cite`d? In other words, I'd like to change the abovementioned "default inclusion threshold" so that it does not automatically include parents.

(I know I can use the options `longcrossref=true` or `=false` to determine whether parts of the same collection will be represented in abbreviated form or not, but I couldn't find anywhere to set whether or not the parent will be included at all.)

Comment: Check the `mincrossrefs`/`minxrefs` options from the `biblatex` manual. If you need further help an MWE would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @moewe Yey, excellent, that's what I was looking for!  Thank you.  I wish there was a reference to that in the `biblatex-chicago` manual.

Comment: Mhhh, yes, the `biblatex-chicago` documentation presupposes knowledge of basic `biblatex` options/basics of the `biblatex` manual, so it doesn't mention all standard options again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options `mincrossrefs`/`minxrefs` control the threshold after which a `crossref`'d/`xref`'d 'parent' entry appears in the bibliography even if it was not cited itself.
You'll find a bit more about that in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the default value for both options is `2`.